# Tips on navigating through thousands of web pages and scraping them?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, phantomjs

I need to scrape data from an html table with about **20,000 rows**. The table, however, is separated into 200 pages with 100 rows in each page. The problem is that I need to click on a link in each row to access the necessary data.

**I was wondering if anyone had any tips to go about doing this because my current method, shown below, is taking far too long.**

The first portion is necessary for navigating through Shiboleth. This part is not my concern as it only takes around 20 seconds and happens once.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select # for <SELECT> HTML form

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()

# Here I had to select my school among others 
driver.get("http://onesearch.uoregon.edu/databases/alphabetical")
driver.find_element_by_link_text("Foundation Directory Online Professional").click()
driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Login with your').click()

# We are now on the login in page where we shall input the information.
driver.find_element_by_name('j_username').send_keys("blahblah")
driver.find_element_by_name('j_password').send_keys("blahblah")
driver.find_element_by_id('login_box_container').submit()

# Select the Search Grantmakers by I.D.
print driver.current_url
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/header/div/div[2]/nav/ul/li[2]/a").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='name']").send_keys("family")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='name']").submit()
```

***This is the part that is taking too long.*** The scraping part is not included in this code.

```
# Now I need to get the page source for each link of 20299 pages... :()
list_of_links = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("a[class='profile-gate-check search-result-link']")

# Hold the links in a list instead of the driver.
list_of_linktext = []
for link in list_of_links:
    list_of_linktext.append(link.text)

# This is the actual loop that clicks on each link on the page.
for linktext in list_of_linktext:
    driver.find_element_by_link_text(linktext).click()
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)
    print driver.current_url
    driver.back()
    driver.implicitly_wait(5) #Waits to make sure that the page is reached.
```

Navigating 1 out of the 200 pages takes about 15 minutes. Is there a better way to do this?

I tried using an explicit wait instead of an implicit wait.

```
for linktext in list_of_linktext:
    # explicit wait
    WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[class='profile-gate-check search-result-link']"))
    )
    driver.find_element_by_link_text(linktext).click()
    print driver.current_url
    driver.back()
```

The problem, however, still persists with an avg time of 5 seconds before each page.

Comment: Have you tried mechanize? It's quicker than selenium

Comment: @Rishub I initially tried mechanize but I was having issues with navigating through links that required a couple transient pages to load. Thanks for the advice though, I may try to rework this in mechanize if there are no other options.

Comment: Open a browser's network analyzer, and see what call(s) is/are made when you click the 'next' button, and try to replicate that. Depending on the implementation of the site, the solution may be a lot simpler than what you have here

Comment: Thanks for the advice @Ryan. Could you point me to some resources so I can try to implement what you are describing?

Comment: The long running time obviously comes from the implicit wait. You need to wait for a selector rather than a static amount of time.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Thanks for the reply. After using explicit wait, I found that it still takes around 5 seconds for each round in the loop which is around the same as the implicit wait.

Comment: @Savvak could you provide a link to the site or a description of the network analysis? The only resources you might need are a browsers network analyzer (try F12 to open the developer tools) and some standard python libs like json, requests, urllib

Comment: Thanks @Ryan. I found what you were talking about and I will try to do that.

Answer (score 0):

For screen scraping, I normally steer clear of Selenium altogether.  There are faster, more reliable ways to scrape data from a website.

If you're using Python, you might give [beautifulsoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) a try.  It seems very similar to other site-scraping tools I've used in the past for other languages (most notably JSoup and NSoup).

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I am currently using beautifulsoup to scrape the data but the problem right now is just navigating to the pages in order to scrape the data. The navigation itself is taking too long.